# Getting an exception writing a boolean to sql using a datatable and SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

It works fine for all other datatypes, but I am unable to get it to work with a 'bit' column.

This is my SQL for doing the bulk write:

```
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls))
{
    bulk.BatchSize = 2000;
    bulk.DestinationTableName = targetTable;
    bulk.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

This is my datatable:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Clear();

    dt.Columns.Add("MyBool", typeof(bool)); // Tried with and without typeof(bool)

    return dt;
```

This is how I construct the row before adding it to the datatable.

`personAssociationRow["MyBool"] = true;`

The exception is thrown on the WriteToServer line, and depending on if the `typeof(bool)` is specified is either:

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MyBool', table` but intellisense/debugger shows the value as `true`

or

`The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column.` which is when the value in the intellisense/debugger becomes `"True"` ie a string.

In the database, the column is defined as `bit` and does not allow nulls.

Any ideas how I can get my boolean to work?

Edit : Just found and tried `SqlBoolean` as a type too but that didn't work, it said `The given value of type SqlBoolean from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column.` which suggests int would work, but it does not seem to.

Edit: I suspect the problem lies in it thinking the underlying database is type `int` when it is clear as purple crayon that the type is `bit`, hence the error message about it not converting to underlying type `int`.

Comment: Try to use `int` datatype with `0` for `false` and `1` for `true` values instead of `bool`

Comment: Tries, says does not allow NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, turns out it was a mapping problem. For some reason, all 20 other tables mapped completely fine, but this table didn't map correctly until I added the following:

`bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Ex", "Ex");`

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue: setting bool column to true/false was ignored by bulk copy, all values were set to null. The previous answer helped to resolve it, but I had to add mappings for all columns to make it work:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
}
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say: `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls`

You meant: `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls`

The first one evaluates to zero.

Comment: It's a bitwise include of both properties

Comment: @SLC no, it is a bitwise AND. You need bitwise OR to set both bits.

Comment: Interesting, I copied it from another SO question, I will change it

Comment: Not sure if that's going to fix your problem, but surely it is a bug.